# For loop to calculate a mathematical expression

Tags: python, loops, math

[image: image description goes here]How to write a Python for loop that calculate the following xN1i0 and xN2i0 for N times ? First should be zero! then goes up!

```
xSpanN1=0.232e-6 
xSpanN2=0.09688e-6

xN1i0 = 0.0
xN2i0 = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN1i0

xN1i1 = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN2i0
xN2i1 = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN1i1

xN1i2 = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN2i1
xN2i2 = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN1i2

xN1i3 = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN2i2
xN2i3 = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN1i3
....
..
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

drop the numbers at the end of the names for iterations, just use two variables and put them in a for loop.

```
xSpanN1=0.232e-6 
xSpanN2=0.09688e-6

xN1i = 0.0
xN2i = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN1i

for _ in range(20):
    xN1i = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN2i
    xN2i = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN1i
```

Comment: The problem I'm facing here is i want xN1i to start with 0 and then it start increasing as calculating the expression @kinshukdua

Comment: That is what's happening.

Comment: `
xSpanN1=0.232e-6 
xSpanN2=0.09688e-6

xN1i = 0.0
xN2i = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN1i

n=10

for _ in range(n):
    
    xN1i = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN2i
    xN2i = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN1i
    fdtd.set("x",xN1i)
`

I want the first xN1i to be zero then increases @kinshukdua

Comment: You're missing that the OP asked for the first pair of variable name to be `xN1i0` and `xN2i0`,  not `xN1i` and `xN2i`, and that the OP asked that the names increment, i.e. the last character should be `n`, where `n` is the number of the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need two variables, calculate `xN1i` and remove `((xSpanN1 / 2) + (xSpanN2 / 2))` from it to get `xN12`

```
xSpanN1 = 0.232e-6
xSpanN2 = 0.09688e-6
xSpan = ((xSpanN1 / 2) + (xSpanN2 / 2))

xN1i = 0.0
for _ in range(10):
    xN1i += xSpan
xN12 = xN1i - xSpan
```

Or with generator expresion and `sum`

```
xN1i = sum(xSpan for _ in range(10))
xN12 = xN1i - xSpan
```

Comment: didn't work, I want first xN1i to be zero then increase > find code > 
`
xSpanN1=0.232e-6 
xSpanN2=0.09688e-6

xN1i = 0.0
xN2i = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN1i

n=10

for _ in range(n):
 
    xN1i = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN2i
    xN2i = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN1i
    
    fdtd.set("x",xN1i)`

Comment: @KhalilJouma What do you mean by *didn't work*?

Comment: find the code where i want to use values xN1i and xN2i  >>xSpanN1=0.232e-6 
xSpanN2=0.09688e-6

xN1i = 0.0
xN2i = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN1i

n=10

for _ in range(n):
    
    xN1i = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN2i
    xN2i = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN1i

    fdtd.set("x",xN1i) <<

Comment: find code above i just want to get first xNi1=0 then it increase

Comment: @KhalilJouma `xNi1=0` doesn't have to be set to 0. Did you try my code and got different results from the expected?

Comment: yes I tried and yes i got different results

Comment: @KhalilJouma What did you expect to `xN1i` and `xN12` to be?

Comment: first xN1i=0 , xN2i=((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN1i and so on for n number @Guy

Comment: @KhalilJouma This is not what I asked. If `n = 10`, what should be the final value of `xN1i` and `xN12`.

Comment: the final should be according to n=10 after repeat calculation 10 times

Comment: @KhalilJouma What is the ***expected value***

Comment: 3.12436 for n=10 @Guy

Comment: @KhalilJouma Do you mean the result of `xN1i + xN12`? my code produces that result.

Comment: if you try this code > 
xSpanN1=0.232e-6 
xSpanN2=0.09688e-6

xN1i = 0.0
xN2i=0

n=10

for i in range(n):
    
    xN1i = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN2i
    xN2i = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN1i
    
    print(xN1i)
    print(xN2i)  > I want first printed xN1i=0 Please try this code @Guy

Comment: @KhalilJouma This is not the code I posted, please try it.

Comment: Nope the code you posted didn't work at all @Guy

Comment: @KhalilJouma It works for me, did you change anything?

Comment: yes i solved it > xSpanN1=0
xSpanN2=0

xN2i = 0
xN1i = 0.0

n=10

for _ in range(n):
    
    xN1i = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN2i
    xSpanN1=0.232e-6 
    xSpanN2=0.09688e-6 
    xN2i = ((xSpanN1/2)+(xSpanN2/2))+xN1i

Answer (score 0):

```
increment = xSpanN1/2+xSpanN2/2
[xN1i0,xN1i0,
    xN1i1,xN1i1,
    xN1i2,xN1i2,
    xN1i3,xN1i3,
    #....
] = range(increment*N, increment)
```

You could dynamically generate the name `xN1i0` etc. with, for instance, `eval`.

```
eval('['+,','.join(['xN1i{},xN2i{}'.format(n,n) 
                for n in range(N)])+']') =
    range(increment*N, increment)
```

It's also probably a good idea to pad the variable names, for instance:

```
import math
def var_names(n, num_length = math.log(N,10)):
    num_string = str(n).zfill(num_length)
    return 'xN1i{},xN2i{}'.format(
             num_string, num_string)

eval('['+,','.join([var_names(n) 
                for n in range(N)])+']') =
    range(increment*N, increment)
```